# find(params[:id]) and instance variable returns <Object>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Within my Images Controller I have a `show` action

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @image = Image.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

When I am on a page `/images/6` the `params[:id]` is 6

Routes

```
resources :images, only: [:show]
```

So on this page I have a form_for to write to a different model, within a hidden field (for now) I have

```
<%= form_for(@cart_item, url: cart_item_path, :remote => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :image_id, value: @image %>
<% end %>
```

Now I would expect the value to equal 6, but when I inspect it the value is `#<Image:0x007fe41413b528>`, thus when submitting the form saves the image_id as 0.

And I also realise that if I put @image.id i would get the id, but that's not the way I thought it worked

What am I missing?

Comment: `Image.find(params[:id])` is equivalent to `Image.find(6)`, i.e. it returns the `Image` record with id 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing it like `@image.id`

```
<%= f.hidden_field :image_id, value: @image.id %>
```

`@image` holds the ***record***, not ***id***

Comment: thanks @Pavan, slight misunderstanding of me thinking that providing just `@image` would give me the id